# Making ReasonML/Bucklescript output ES5 compatible code

Tags: reason, bucklescript

While using ReasonML and Bucklescript, is it possible to configure Bucklescript so it won't generate `export` statements? I'd prefer if the generated code could be used as is in a browser, that is, being ES5 (or ES6) compatible.

**Edit**: OK, while trying out the tool chain a bit more, I realize just turning off the `export` is not enough. See example below:

```
function foo(x, y) {
  return x + y | 0;
}

var Test = /* module */[
  /* foo */foo
];

exports.Test = Test;
```

This code will pollute global namespace if `exports` is removed, and is simply broken from an ES5 compatibility viewpoint.

**Edit 2**: Reading on Bucklescript's blog, this seems not possible:

> one OCaml module compiled into one JavaScript module (AMDJS, CommonJS, or Google module) without name mangling.

[Source](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BuckleScript can output modules in a number of different module formats, which can then be bundled up along with their dependencies using a bundler such as webpack or rollup. The output is not really intended to be used as a stand-alone unit, since you'd be rather limited in what you could do in any case, as the standard and runtime libraries are separate modules. And even something as trivial as multiplication will involve the runtime library.

You can configure BuckleScript to output es6 modules, which can be run directly in the browser as long as your browser supports it. But that would still require manually extracting the standard and runtime libraries from your bs-platform installation.

The module format is configured through the `package-specs` property in `bsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "packages-specs": ["es6-global"] /* Or "es6" */
}
```

Having said all that, you actually *can* turn off exports by putting `[@@@bs.config { no_export }]` at the top of the file. But this is undocumented since it's of very limited use in practice, for the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe this information or something similar can be added to https://reasonml.github.io/guide/javascript/quickstart/? Or make two new pages, one quickstart for browser, another for native?

Comment: This is more of a BuckleScript than a Reason thing. The BuckleScript website and documentation will be overhauled in the near future, similar to what's recently been done with Reason and ReasonReact. I expect the documentation will be greatly improved then (and will personally contribute to that improvement).